# What is importance sampling?

Tags: variance, simulation, monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator, importance-sampling

I'm trying to learn reinforcement learning and this topic is really confusing to me. I have taken an introduction to statistics, but I just couldn't understand this topic intuitively.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Importance sampling is **a form of sampling from a distribution different from the distribution of interest** to more easily obtain better estimates of a parameter from the distribution of interest. Typically this will provide estimates of the parameter with a lower variance than would be obtained by sampling directly from the original distribution with the same sample size.

It is applied in various contexts. In general sampling from the different distributions allows for more samples to be taken **in a portion of the distribution of interest that is dictated by the application (important region).**

One example might be that you want to have a sample that includes more samples from the tails of the distribution than pure random sampling from the distribution of interest would provide.

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling) that I have seen on this subject is too abstract.  It is better to look at various specific examples. However, it does include links to interesting applications such as **Bayesian Networks.**

One example of importance sampling in the 1940s and 1950s is a variance reduction technique (a form of the Monte Carlo Method).  See for example **the book Monte Carlo Methods by Hammersley and Handscomb published as a Methuen Monograph/Chapman and Hall in 1964 and reprinted in 1966 and later by other publishers.**   **Section 5.4** of the book covers **Importance Sampling.**

Comment: To add to this: In RL you are generally applying importance sampling to the policy: e.g. sampling actions from an exploration policy instead of the actual policy that you truly want to sample

Comment: This reply starts out well by explaining what importance sampling *does,* but I was disappointed to find it never actually answers the question of what importance sampling *is*: how does it work?

Comment: @whuber My goal here was to explain the concept to a confused OP and point him to some literature.  It is a big topic and is used in seemingly different applications.  Others may be able to explain the details in simple terms better than I can. I know that when you decide to answer a question you go whole hog and provide nice graphs, go through technical details using plain language. Those post almost always satisfy the community with its clearness and completeness and I dare say also satisfies the OP at least in part. Perhaps a few sentences with equations would suffice as you suggest.

Comment: Maybe that is better for the community to be put into an answer to the question rather than just pointing to other sources or even providing links. I just felt that what I did was adequate and the OP who admits to being a statistics novice should make some effort on his own first.

Comment: You have a point. I wonder, though, whether it might be possible in just one or two more sentences--no math, no graphs, hardly any extra work--to provide an answer to the question as asked. In this case the description would have to emphasize that one is estimating the *expectation* (not just any "parameter"), then perhaps point out that since the expectation sums a product of values and probabilities, one gets the same result by changing the probabilities (to those of a distribution that is easy to sample from) and adjusting the values to compensate for that.

Answer (score 43):

Importance sampling is a simulation or Monte Carlo method intended for approximating integrals. The term "sampling" is somewhat confusing in that it does not intend to provide samples from a given distribution.

The intuition behind [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling) is that a well-defined integral, like
$$\mathfrak{I}=\int_\mathfrak{X} h(x)\,\text{d}x$$
can be expressed as an expectation for a wide range of probability distributions:
$$\mathfrak{I}=\mathbb{E}_f[H(X)]=\int_\mathfrak{X} H(x)f(x)\,\text{d}x$$
where $f$ denotes the density of a probability distribution and $H$ is determined by $h$ and $f$. *(Note that $H(\cdot)$ is usually different from $h(\cdot)$.)* Indeed, the choice
$$H(x)=\dfrac{h(x)}{f(x)}$$leads to the equalities $H(x)f(x)=h(x)$ and $\mathfrak{I}=\mathbb{E}_f[H(X)]$$-$under some restrictions on the support of $f$, meaning $f(x)>0$ when $h(x)\ne 0$$-$. Hence, as pointed out by W. Huber in his comment, there is no unicity in the representation of an integral as an expectation, but on the opposite an infinite array of such representations, some of which are better than others once a criterion to compare them is adopted. For instance, Michael Chernick mentions choosing $f$ towards reducing the variance of the estimator.

Once this elementary property is understood, the implementation of the idea is to rely on the Law of Large Numbers as in other Monte Carlo methods, i.e., to simulate [via a pseudo-random generator] an iid sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ distributed from $f$ and to use the approximation
$$\hat{\mathfrak{I}}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n H(x_i)$$which

1. is an unbiased estimator of $\mathfrak{I}$
2. converges almost surely to $\mathfrak{I}$

Depending on the choice of the distribution $f$, the above estimator $\hat{\mathfrak{I}}$ may or may not have a finite variance. However, there always exist choices of $f$ that allow for a finite variance and even for an arbitrarily small variance (albeit those choices may be unavailable in practice). And there also exist choices of $f$ that make the importance sampling estimator $\hat{\mathfrak{I}}$ a very poor approximation of ${\mathfrak{I}}$. This includes all the choices where the variance gets infinite, even though [a recent paper by Chatterjee and Diaconis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01437) studies how to compare importance samplers with infinite variance. The picture below is taken from [my blog discussion](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/importance-sampling-with-infinite-variance/) of [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01437) and illustrates the poor convergence of infinite variance estimators.

[image: Importance sampling with importance distribution an Exp(1) distribution target distribution an Exp(1/10) distribution, and function of interest $h(x)=x$. The true value of the integral is $10$.]

> Importance sampling with importance distribution an Exp(1)
>   distribution target distribution an Exp(1/10) distribution, and
>   function of interest $h(x)=x$. The true value of the integral is $10$.

*[The following is reproduced from our book [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392).]*

The following example from Ripley (1987) shows why it may actually pay to generate from a distribution other than the (original) distribution $f$ appearing in the integral
$$\int_\mathfrak{X}  h(x) f(x)\,\text{d}x$$of interest or, in other words, to
modify the representation of an integral as an expectation against a
given density.

**Example (Cauchy tail probability)**
Suppose that the quantity of interest is the probability, $p$, that
a Cauchy ${\mathcal{C}}(0,1)$ variable
is larger than $2$, that is,
$$
p = \int_2^{+\infty} \; {1\over \pi(1 + x^2)} \; \text{d}x \;.
$$
When $p$ is evaluated through the empirical average
$$
{\hat{p}}_1 = {1\over m} \; \sum_{j=1}^m \; \mathbb{I}_{X_{j} > 2}
$$
of an iid sample $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ $\sim$ $\; \mathcal{C}(0,1)$, the
variance of this estimator is $p(1-p)/m$ (equal to $0.127/m$ since $p=0.15$).

This variance can be reduced by taking into account the
symmetric nature of ${\mathcal{C}}(0,1)$, since the average
$$
{\hat{p}}_2 = {1\over 2m} \; \sum_{j=1}^m \; \mathbb{I}_{|X_{j}| > 2}
$$
has variance $p(1-2p)/2m$ equal to $0.052/m$.

The (relative) inefficiency of these methods is due to the generation
of values outside the domain of interest, $[2,+\infty)$, 
which are, in some sense,
irrelevant for the approximation of $p$. [This relates to Michael Chernick mentioning tail area estimation.]  If $p$ is written as
$$
p = {1\over 2} - \int_0^2 \; {1\over \pi(1 + x^2)} \; \text{d}x \;,
$$
the integral above can be considered to be the expectation of
$h(X) = 2/\pi(1 + X^2)$, where $X \sim {\mathcal{U}}_{[0, 2]}$.
An alternative method of evaluation for $p$ is therefore
$$
{\hat{p}}_3 = {1\over 2} - {1\over m} \; \sum_{j=1}^m \; h(U_j)
$$
for $U_j \sim {\mathcal{U}}_{[0,2]}$. The variance of ${\hat{p}}_3$ is
$(\mathbb{E}[h^2] - \mathbb{E}[h]^2)/m$ and an integration by parts shows that
it is equal to $0.0285/m$.  Moreover, since $p$ can be written as
$$ 
p = \int_0^{1/2} \; {y^{-2}\over \pi(1 + y^{-2})} \; \text{d}y \;,
$$
this integral can also be seen as the expectation of
${1\over 4} \; h(Y) = 1/2\pi(1 + Y^2)$ against the
uniform distribution on $[0,1/2]$ and another evaluation of $p$ is
$$
{\hat{p}}_4 = {1\over 4 m} \; \sum_{j=1}^m \; h(Y_j)
$$
when $Y_j \sim {\mathcal{U}}_{[0,1/2]}$. The same integration by
parts shows that the variance of ${\hat{p}}_{4}$ is then
$0.95 \; 10^{-4}/m$.

Compared with ${\hat{p}}_1$, the reduction in variance brought by ${\hat p}_4$
is of order $10^{-3}$, which implies, in
particular, that this evaluation requires
$\sqrt{1000} \approx 32$ times fewer simulations than $\hat p_1$
to achieve the same precision. $\blacktriangleright$

Comment: Thank you @Xi' an for going to the trouble of illustrating importance sampling in a way that everyone can appreciate and I think more than satisfies Bill Huber's request.  +1

Comment: I want to note that initially this post was put on hold and thanks to the contributions of several people.  We have come up with an informative thread.

Comment: Christian, I want to extend my thanks and express a feeling of privilege that you are actively sharing such excellent material with us.

Comment: I just want to add a thank you to Xi'an who was kind enough to make a few edits to improve my answer even though he gave one of his own.

Comment: This has to be one of the best posts on stats.stackexchange. Thanks for sharing!